# WHERE clause (multiple tables)

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am working on a project and I am trying to get a return from a database. I'm new to Webdesign and ASP.net so I don't really know exactly how to word my question but I'll try to explain it the best I can. I have a drop down list that returns an authorID, and I am trying to use that to display the information on screen.

Here all my tables that I am using (first line will be title of the table with the points below the data names with an * by the ones in the select statement to help visualize it)

```
Authors:
    authorID
 *  firstName
 *  lastName

AuthorISBN:
    ISBN
    authorID

Titles:
 *  ISBN
 *  title
 *  editionNumber
    description
    publisherID
    copyright
    imageFile
 *  price


Publishers:
    publisherID
 *  publisherName
```

Heres what I got so far on my SELECT statement so far.

```
SELECT  Authors.firstName, Authors.lastName, Titles.ISBN, Titles.title, 
        Publishers.publisherName, Titles.price, Titles.editionNumber

FROM    (((Authors INNER JOIN AuthorISBN ON Authors.authorID = 
        AuthorISBN.authorID) INNER JOIN Titles ON AuthorISBN.ISBN = 
        Titles.ISBN) INNER JOIN Publishers ON Titles.publisherID = 
        Publishers.publisherID)
```

Now in a previous project with a similar problem to this one I used (but only one table)

```
WHERE (CategoryID = @CategoryID)
```

then asp.net popped up another window letting me chose the source of the input; but with this assignment it doesnt compile

```
WHERE (authorID = @authorID)
```

because authorID is in multiple tables. I don't know how or exactly how the syntax would work to do what I am trying to. and if its relevant the drop down list ID is ddlAuthors and it returns the value authorID from the Authors table.

Thanks to anyone who took the time to read or reply.

Answer (score 0):

As there are couple of tables with the Same column, there is ambiguity as to which table this filter to be applied.

To resolve this, you could specify the table name.column name to remove this ambiguity.

In your case, use Authors.authorid = @authorid if this is the table you wanted the apply the filter

Comment: I tried that and it said (no value given for one or more required parameters)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.firstName, a.lastName, t.ISBN, t.title, 
        p.publisherName, t.price, t.editionNumber

FROM Authors a, AuthorISBN aisbn, Titles t, Publishers p

WHERE a.authorID = aisbn.authorID
AND a.authorID = ${your author ID from the dropdown}
AND aisbn.ISBN = t.ISBN
AND t.publisherID = p.publishedID
```

This is a simpler way to understand it in case you had any trouble with the long INNER JOINs (it's better to separate your SQL in lines so you can read it better and make sure you're joining what/where you want to). Let me know if the above works. I may not be answering your question on the passed parameter part (in which case I misunderstood your question). If this doesn't answer the question, let me know, as this is basic SQL (I'm not familiar with asp.net).

Comment: I couldnt get it to compile. what would go in the { } exactly? the dropdown list's id is ddlAuthors and returns authorID from the authors table.

Comment: That was meant to be replaced by you with the correct code like `Request.Form["ddlAuthors"].ToString()`, sorry I didn't make that clear. I'm not familiar with asp.net - I was trying to help with the SQL part to simplify it for you and separate each join for the purpose of understanding. Note, you would need to read up on how to do this properly, as the input needs to be cleaned or parameterized to safeguard against SQL Injection